# tocloft does not work with list of subfigure in List of Figure?

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption, tocloft

If I load the following:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily}
```

and below (below is the add in subfigure in the List of Figure)

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
```

The list of subfigure does not appear in List of Figure.

The full MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{One}
\section{One}

\begin{figure}[!b]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 1}
            \label{fig:arm1}
        \end{subfigure}
    %

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 2}
            \label{fig:arm2}
        \end{subfigure}


            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 3}
            \label{fig:arm2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{$Q^{*}$ values for different arms}


          \end{figure}
    %

    \begin{figure}[htb]\ContinuedFloat
        \centering

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 4}
            \label{fig:arm3}
        \end{subfigure}
    %
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 5}
            \label{fig:arm4}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{$Q^{*}$ values for different arms (cont.)}
        \label{fig:arms}
    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If I cancel off:

```
% \usepackage{tocloft}
% \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please prepare a MWE?

Comment: @leandriis, sorry for that. I eddited my question and added MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `tocloft` package it will take control of the look+feel of the List of Figures, furthermore it offers an own mechanism for filtering subfigures from the list which was inherited from the (obsolete) `subfigure` package.

With

```
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
```

(after loading of the `tocloft` package) the subfigures will be listed in the LOF.

Unfortunately this mechanism is only documented in the `subfigure` package documentation, and not in the `tocloft` package documentation.

Comment: thanks. It works. Brillant. Can I know what is the meaning of `2` in `setcounter{lofdepth}{2}` in simple explanation?

Comment: @aan `1` means "only show main figures", `2` means "show main + subfigures" in the listing. This mechanism is copied from the LaTeX counter `tocdepth` (offered by LaTeX itself) which does the same thing for the Table of Content.

Comment: thanks. Noted now. So i guess the maximum is `2`. there impossible to have `3`

Comment: Related: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/15

Comment: @aan You could certainly have 3, but that would do nothing unless there were subsubfigures.