# formatting table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I currently have my chapters formatted as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@startsection
    {chapter}{1}{0mm}%% name, level, indent
   {\presectionskip}% % beforeskip
    {\postsectionskip}% % afterskip
    {\fontsize{18}{18}\bfseries}}
```

and I use the librecasion package to get the font I like:

```
\usepackage{librecaslon}
```

I have generate the table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables, but there a few issues that I am struggling to solve:

1. I want the title "Table of contents", "List of tables", and "List of figures" to look exactly as the chapter titles do. So libre caslon font, size 18, centered, bold
2. I want to create some space between the various entries of the table of contents/figures/tables (note that in the table of contents there are many chapters, sections, and subsections)
3. I want the dots "......" in the table of contents to be closer to one another so that it looks like a line, as opposed to ". . . . . . . "
4. Currently, when I have a table 10 (or larger) the following happens in the list of tables.

> C.13.This is the title of table 13 in appendix C..............450

The problem is that 13. is glued to This, and I want a space. This only happens when the table number is larger or equal to 10. It should look like:

> ```
> C.13. This is the title of table 13 in appendix C..............450
> ```

For completeness, note that I create the numbering of the tables as follows:

```
\renewcommand\thetable{C.\arabic{table}.}
```

If you have enough spare time, I would be very grateful if you could also explain the reasoning behind the code so that I can really learn. Thanks.

Comment: Use the `tocloft` package. The manual tells you how to do all the things you want (except perhaps your number 2).

Comment: Please be more specific as to "create some space between the various entries of the ToC, LoT, LoF" might entail. And, please tell us which document class you employ. Incidentally, why do you hard-code "C" (the appendix number, right) in `\renewcommand\thetable{C.\arabic{table}.}`? Incidentally, are the appendices grouped together at the very end of the document, or are there appendices at the end of each chapter?

Comment: Don't reinvent  the wheel: `titlesec`  has an `numberless` key for the formatting of unnumbered chapters, and furthermore, it has  a companion package – `titletoc`.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently trying these suggestions out. I'll update you on how it goes. @Mico : I want to have enough flexibility to create arbitrary space (whatever I think it looks good on the page). So I would like to experiment with spaces of 0.2, 0.5,..1 cm and see what looks best. I am using report class. I hard-coded it because I only have three appendices and was experimenting a bit, and it worked fine and I ended up not changing it

Comment: @PeterWilson : I have been trying for a few days now to use the tocloft package but it simply won't work. I tried loading it by itseldf with subfigure package as suggested here(https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522538/tocloft-does-not-work-with-list-of-subfigure-in-list-of-figure), I changed the position of the package in the preamble, I loaded hyperref after loading tocloft,etc, I can't get it to work. I've tried : \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}.. but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: So, for example, if I load tocloft (\usepackage[tocloft]
) and then I load hyperref (\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
) I get messages: (i) "! Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }.", (ii) "! Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@pti@ns was complete.", (iii)"! Paragraph ended before \reserved@b was complete.", (iv) "! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.", (v)"! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}."; (vi) "! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 125."

Comment: and if I deactivate hyperref package, and substitute it for "\documentclass[10.0pt,hidelinks]{report}", and load tocloft I get message "!incomplete \ifx"

Comment: The workings of the `hyperref` package are a mystery to me; all I know is that it should be the last of the packages. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem and what you have tried.